# How can I handle a lot of animation to update UI without freezing?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, android-animation

I have indicators that has linear progress bars and text that displays percentage.

Each indicator has 3 kind of linear progress bars and each linear progress bar has text view next to it to show the percentage.

I am using RecyclerView and I update them like this in Adapter.

```
startAnimationIndicator(type1, item.oldValue, item.newValue, holder.textView, midProgressbar, holder.indicator)
startAnimationIndicator(type2, item.oldValue, item.newValue, holder.textView, midProgressbar, holder.indicator)
startAnimationIndicator(type3, item.oldValue, item.newValue, holder.textView, midProgressbar, holder.indicator)
```

And startAnimationIndicator() method looks like this

```
if(newValue > oldValue){
// increasing
indicator.animate()
         .setDuration(5000L)
         .setInterpolator{
             val progressValue = (oldValue + (newValue - oldValue) * it).toInt()
             tv.setText("$progressValue")
             indicator.progress = if (progressValue > 100) 100 else progressValue
         }.start()
// ...
}else if(oldValue > newValue){
// decreasing
indicator.animate()
         .setDuration(5000L)
         .setInterpolator{
             val progressValue = (oldValue + (newValue - oldValue) * it).toInt()
             tv.setText("$progressValue")
             indicator.progress = if (progressValue > 100) 100 else progressValue
             it
         }.start()
// ...
}else{
// no animation
    tv.setText("$newValue")
    indicator.progress = newValue.progress
}
```

Since startAnimationIndicator() is called three times, and each of them starts animation almost at the time time. They make UI thread busy and it can cause skipping UI frame.

So, in this case, what's the better solution to avoid freezing and use the resource efficiently?

Comment: maybe you could start thiose animation on different threads.

Comment: @primo Well, Android uses only Main Thread for updating the UI.

Comment: Sorry if this isn't exactly what you asked for, but if possible, you should try to migrate your UI to Jetpack Compose. I used to have the same issue as you (and BTW, it runs significantly better in a proper release vs. the debug version), but Compose just made everything run much smoother